# I want open CMD.exe from the UWP application

Tags: command-line, uwp

I have a requirement for open printing preference UI from the UWP app. so I need to execute command-line arguments from the UWP application.

Answer (score 0):

> I want open CMD.exe from the UWP application

For launching command-line from UWP application, the better way is using desktop extension to approach. you can refer to stefan's blog **UWP with Desktop Extension part2** and open the launcher with [`LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.fulltrustprocesslauncher.launchfulltrustprocessforcurrentappasync?view=winrt-22621) method then call process start to open command-line app.

Comment: but it is not working for me.

Comment: Does not  it launch cmd ?

Comment: Yes.not able to run

Comment: Could you share the cmd path parameter for process start method ?

Comment: I have tested base on above sample, and replace mstsc.exe with cmd.exe. and it could launch cmd successfully

Comment: Please share your error, I will troubleshoot base on it.

Comment: uwp package mainfest

Comment: You may miss Windows winmd file for  launcher project

Comment: Any updates for this thread ? can you run the project now?

Comment: It is working for me. but my requirement is single application project manifest file.

Comment: The manifest capability of the packaged project will replace the uwp manifest, which you can think of as a single manifest file